# Django MEDIA_URL with CDN and Admin media

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using, in a Django 1.3 project, a CDN for media resources like images, css and such. I have a problem serving admin resources, what I made is:

In `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://cdn.test.com/' 
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
```

In `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
(r'^admin_media/(.*)', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root' : 'django/contrib/admin/media/',
         'show_indexes' : True}),
```

Looking at the admin HTML I see something like `/admin_media/css/base.css` but all resources return `http 404`. I can't understand what is wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # (... other urls ...)
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Also, the `document_root` you refer to in your `urls.py` should be an absolute path: this might also cause some issues. The above should replace this for your Django version, though.

Comment: Are You sure about staticfiles_urlpatterns()? I made a try but it give me an error: NameError: name 'staticfiles_urlpatterns' is not defined

Comment: If you are indeed using Django 1.3, then yes. Did you include the import statement in your code?

Comment: Sorry, You right I forgot imports. But it doesn't works. A note: if I try using manage.py runserver ... I can see admin resources but with webserver (in my case lighttpd) I can't.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I assumed you were using the devserver. But that's a good step at least: what's left is the deployment then. Do the steps defined in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles) help you out (especially the section on deployment)?